# rChart forceY multiBar "Bar start" not correct in rmarkdown

Tags: r, rcharts

when I run the r code in the console, I get the output I expected, but when I run it in rmarkdown I get this result:

[image: The bars do not start at my forced y = 0.4]

````
The complete rmarkdown minimum example looks like this:

---
title: "Untitled"
author: "sda"
output: html_document
---


```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rCharts)
library(data.table)
```

```{r results = 'asis', comment = F, message = F, tidy = F, echo=F, cache=F}

myData <- data.table(XAxis = rep(seq(0,length.out = 3),each = 2),
                     Value = c(0.6,0.8,0.4,0.55,0.87,0.42),
                     Type = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"))

  #' Create a multiBarChart using nvd3 of rCharts
  plot <- nPlot(Value ~ XAxis, group = 'Type', 
                            data = myData, type = 'multiBarChart')

  plot$chart(forceY = c(0.5, 1))
 plot$show('iframesrc', cdn = TRUE)


```
Look the bars start too low
````

So the forceY does not seem to work correctly. Is there an easy workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest workaround is to save the plot and display it in an iframe. 
Your example would look as follows:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "sda"
output: html_document
---


```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rCharts)
library(data.table)
```

```{r results = 'asis', comment = F, message = F, tidy = F, echo=F, cache=F}

myData <- data.table(XAxis = rep(seq(0,length.out = 3),each = 2),
                     Value = c(0.6,0.8,0.4,0.55,0.87,0.42),
                     Type = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"))


  plot <- nPlot(Value ~ XAxis, group = 'Type', 
                            data = myData, type = 'multiBarChart')

plot$chart(yDomain = c(0.5, 1))
plot$save("plot.html", standalone = TRUE)


```

<iframe src="plot.html" height="500" width="900" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
````

Note that I used `yDomain` instead of  `forceY`. I did this because `forceY` displayed the graph from y=0.4 in my computer. However, the chart will also be shown correctly using `forceY`.

You can find the discussion I got the idea for this solution here: https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/373