# RMD Output syntax hiding & rCharts Package

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am working on RMD output in HTML.

A) I am working on a sentiment analysis problem and have built a sentiment model which works perfectly in RStudio, however, the same on the RMD shows all the processing steps and details.

I have used `echo=FALSE` but I still the see the following output:

```
Loading required package: stringr 
Attaching package: 'stringr'
The following object is masked from 'package:qdap':
The following object is masked from 'package:igraph':%>%
```

B) I am also using rcharts to create charts of the above but as mentioned before I dont see the output in RMarkdown whereas I see the output in RStudio. The code for the same is:

```
p4 <- nPlot(~ score, data = abc.sentiments, type = 'pieChart')
p4$chart(donut = TRUE) 
p4
```

Comment: For A): check the chunk options `warning` and `message`. Concerning your second problem I cannot really say what the problem is. Anyway, the answer to this question might be a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937073/rchart-forcey-multibar-bar-start-not-correct-in-rmarkdown

Comment: A reproducible example would be nice...

Comment: For the first error i have fixed this as while running the stringr package in sentiment.score it throws out the package extractions hence called the library at the start of the RMD doc. For the part B i have moved to ggplot2 as this was urgent required and even calling knitr package and using options(viewer = NULL) as checked on the link shared by Martin did not work.